# Answer appears as black box

Tags: bug, android-app

On my Samsung Galaxy S2 all answers appear as black box. Here is an example:

[image]

I am running Android 4.0.3

Comment: I blame caching.

Comment: This happens to me too on my LG Mach, on both questions and answers...ALL questions and answers, but not comments.